# Magento 1.9.1: Fatal error: Call to a member function setLinkModel() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, fatal-error

When I try to see in the backend "Product Information"/"Related Products" I see this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setLinkModel() on a non-object in   /XXXXXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Link.php on line 105

Same error on the right of the front-end for each products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that this line return null or false `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_link_product_collection')`.
Firs try clearing the cache.
If that changes nothing....
Either the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Link/Product/Collection.php` is missing or there is an extension rewriting this model but it does it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very surprised. The file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Link/Product/Collection.php` is empty, it existing without any characters.
I used Filezilla and its queue to transfer via FTP the latest edition of Magento CE and I can't imagine that some files are empty. Thank you Marius!! Cheers